# Laravel 5 API - Handle arrays

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am work with Laravel 5 and have implemented a working Restful API.  I am trying to allow posts to be created by passing in an array like this...

```
post
  title
  excerpt
  content
  image
post
  title
  excerpt
  content
  image
```

The API currently works great for posting one individual post but how can I handle the array of posts instead?

Does anyone have an example I can see?

Comment: share what code you are using  ? may be you are looking for `insert()`

Comment: I dont understand what the problem is. You got an array, so all you need to do is exec an insert query with all the post values. I suspect there is something with Laravel that makes this hard, but when you dont tell us, we cannot help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using the Resource Controller, you should have a `PostsController` with a method `store()`. I am assuming your request payload is some JSON like this:

```
{"posts": [{"title":"foo"},{"title":"bar"}, …]}
```

So you need to `json_decode` the input. Then pass it to your database:

```
public function store() 
{   
    $posts = json_decode($request->input('posts', '')); 
    if (is_array($posts)) {
        DB::table('posts')->insert($posts);
    }
}
```

There is probably some plugin or middleware or whatever to automatically decode the JSON payload. But apart from that, there is nothing special about doing what you ask for.

If you don't want to use the `store()` method (because it already stores a single Post or something) you can just add another route for your multiple Posts.

Comment: Thank you, all makes sense now

Answer (score 1):

did you try to send JSON in the body? Here is a [link](https://communities.vmware.com/thread/560060) with an example

> Request body could look like the following:
>
> ```
> {  
>    "parameters":[    
>       {    
>          "value":{    
>             "array":{    
>                "elements":[    
>                   {    
>                      "string":{    
>                         "value":"value1"  
>                      }  
>                   },  
>                   {    
>                      "string":{    
>                         "value":"value2"  
>                      }  
>                   },  
>                   {    
>                      "string":{    
>                         "value":"value3"  
>                      }  
>                   }  
>                ]  
>             }  
>          },  
>          "type":"Array/string",  
>          "name":"arrayvariable"  
>       }  
>    ]  
> }
> ```

This will convert the array every time you get it from the DB and every time you save it to the DB.

And here is an example using laravel casting [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38616079/3652823)

> Use attribute casting. Open your IdModel model and add this:
>
> ```
>  protected $casts = [
>      'id' => 'array' ];
> ```

Comment: can you please include the main relevant information from the offisite resources into your answer. When you links die, all that's left is your question whether they tried to send JSON in the body.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will include it!